# MYSQL := is not a valid at this position, expecting an identifier

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The task is create a stored procedure which creates a statistic of students by city. The result should be like  -  -
`

```
delimiter $$
create procedure courcity()
begin
declare list_stud text default '';
 declare _cty varchar(50);
 declare _count int;
 declare _name_stud varchar(50);
declare done integer default FALSE;
declare cty_cur cursor for select cty, count(*) as count from student group by cty order by cty;
declare stud_cur cursor  for select name_stud from student where cty = _cty;
declare continue handler for NOT found set done = TRUE;
    create temporary table return_table(
        cty varchar(50),
        count_stud int,
        list_stud text default ''
    );
begin
declare list_stud text default '';
 declare _cty varchar(50);
 declare _count int;
 declare _name_stud varchar(50);
declare done integer default FALSE;
declare cty_cur cursor for select cty, count(*) as count from student group by cty order by cty;
declare stud_cur cursor  for select name_stud from student where cty = _cty;
open cty_cur;
open stud_cur;
read_loop: LOOP
fetch cty_cur into _cty, _count;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
             read_loop1: loop
            fetch stud_cur into _name_stud;
            if done then leave read_loop1;
            list_stud := list_stud || _name_stud || ', ';//here is the problem
        end loop;
        close stud_cur;
        insert into return_table values (_cty, _count, list_stud);
        list_stud := '';
            end loop;
    close cty_cur;
select * from return_table;
end;$$
delimiter ;
```

`

Can't create this procedure due to this problem.Can't find mistake.

Comment: You have 2 begins..., all declared statements must appear before any other code, || is an or in mysql use concat, use set eg set list_stud := and the end ifs-are you sure you are using mysql??

Answer (score 0):

`IF THEN` must be closed with `END IF;`

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-statement/

```
IF condition THEN 
   statements;
END IF;
```

`||` is definitely not correct in MySQL. on the right side of `:=` you should have a variable or a valid expression.

Comment: thanks, i've closed both of them. But the warning is still existing